# Putting of common method of derived classes in base, where the base doesn't use it

Tags: c#, oop

Is it correct from terms of OOP to put common method of derived classes in base class, where base doesn't (!) use it. As in the example:

```
class Base {
    virtual void CalculateTotal() 
    {
        //calculate without taxes (no need in base)
    }

    void CalculateTaxes()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class A : Base {
   override void CalculateTotal() {
       //...
       CalculateTaxes();
       //...
   }
}

class B : Base {
   override void CalculateTotal() {
       //...
       CalculateTaxes();
       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: just change `CalculateTaxes()` to be `protected`. Apart from that there is no issue here - class is not required to call it's own methods.

Comment: Yes that's fine, but it should be protected.

Answer (score 1):

I think not. 
I'd rather put the CalculateTaxes in a utility class used from both A and B.
Es taxes.Calculate()

or something like this.

Comment: That depends on how zealously you're following DDD

Comment: Yes, true :) I usually tend to make class have only one single concern. So, it seems to me that Taxes require quite a complex class and quite a number of private methods (think not all code for calculating the taxes fits into one single gigantic method). So I'd suggest to not mix up things in this case (if not for some exercise code)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no default functionality for calculating total value and each class, derived from the `Base` should provide it, better to make the `Base` class and the `CalculateTotal` method abstract.